# Is it possible to populate an inputSecret field from a controller variable

Tags: visualforce, inputsecret

I want to populate an inputSecret field with a controller variable value. I thought this would be fine but the value is not displaying:

```
public class MyController {
    public String password {get; set;}
}

<apex:inputSecret value="{!password}" />
```

Possibly this is a security *feature*, but it did not explicitly say this in the VF guide. The value displays fine if I use an inputText element.

Does anyone have any more information regarding this?

Comment: I see the same behavior in a page I did (API 19). I ended up displaying the "characters presently saved" for each field so the user could at least tell that something had been entered. I'm certainly interested to know if something better can be done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to include the "redisplay" attribute with a value of "true".  Per the [Visualforce Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputSecret.htm), this defaults to false.  So, yes, apparently this is a (potentially confusing) "feature".

```
<apex:inputSecret value="{!password}" redisplay="true" />
```

Comment: Note that redisplay shows the masked value, not the actual value.

Comment: @MikeChale, that's correct, as inputSecret is analogous to an HTML password input, and inputText is analogous to a text input.  The redisplay attribute tells the Visualforce interpreter to render the actual value to the client (and the browser displays it as masked characters to the user).

Comment: We have some code that came about as the result of a salesforce security review that deliberately clears the password fields in the controller with the comment "// Ensure secret value not in the view state". (Presumably it's not that hard to pull strings back out of the view state.) Perhaps there is a pattern that avoids that problem and still allows the masked value to be displayed.